# Password Hash validation/checking in DBMS vs. Web-app layer

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have the ability to do password hashing in the Web-app layer of my system or in the DBMS (postgresql's pgcrypto). Is there any advantage to using either or?

For more context, I will be using Amazon's AWS (EC2 and RDS).

The system has various mobile clients which contact the back-end (through one Spring/Hibernate Web App). There is no direct access to the database through these mobile clients, they all must go through the java web app.

EDIT: 
Other tidbits:
HTTP basic authenication over SSL, Stateless/RESTFUL (as much as possible), using the blowfish cipher for hashing with a randomly (well.. psuedo random) generated salt.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: What hashes? What salting algorithm(s)? Have you considered a SSO? What precisely are your design parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the password be synchronized? (used by more than one application) If it is that will be the largest guide. I generally recommend not handling unencrypted passwords any more than you must. On the other hand screwing up password hashes is real easy to do, and hard to fix so use a library that gets security updates. Above all be simple, clean well documented code is even more important when dealing with security.

Comment: Used by multiple clients, but the clients must go through the web app to interact with the database indirectly.

I will be using the blowfish cipher with a randomly generated, per password salt.

Comment: then hash as soon as possible.

Comment: Further research shows that SSL support is only available for MySql and SQL server database engines at this moment, atleast according to Amazon's RDS FAQ. Once I place my RDS instance in a VPS, it wouldn't be public facing/accessible, and I think SSL Wouldn't be as big of a factor then.

I'll take your advice for now (im in early prototyping stages), and hash in web app layer. This way it ensures no ability to snatch a plaintext password in route to the DB.

Thanks for your help!